# Excel VBA calculate and set column width

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying the center the range from B:AE in the center of the screen by adjusting the width of column A.

I'm able to change the width by adding the width as number instead of using AdjColWidth

```
Sub TestWH()

'Get widths
WinWidth = ActiveWindow.UsableWidth
RangeWidth = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:AE1").Width
AdjColWidth = WinWidth - RangeWidth / 2

'If less than 4 then set to 4
If AdjColWidth < 4 Then
    Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 4
Else
    Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = AdjColWidth
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `AdjColWidth` must be less than or equal to 255.  I'm assuming your getting an error, and I'm assuming it is `AdjColWidth` is greater than what is allowed.

Comment: @Demetri you nailed it right on the head.   Here is a link to the limits for excel https://support.office.com/en-my/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: Shouldn't `AdjColWidth = WinWidth - RangeWidth / 2` be `AdjColWidth = (WinWidth - RangeWidth) / 2` ? I mean I know there are limits, but on a 1080p screen a column nearly expands to the whole width at 100% zoom - the number produced by the second formula should be quite a bit smaller (but as you guys say you should check that it's less than 255 before setting it).

Comment: @NickDewitt   yes  otherwise the division happens before the subtraction

Comment: Yeah and you get a larger number than you expect - added to my comment above

Comment: It's also worth noting that `Activewindow.UsableWidth` is in points, whereas one unit of `columnwidth` is equal to the width of one character in the Normal style

Comment: I think you guys are absolutely right about the error coming fram greather than 255. So i have to make an if that states that if AdjColWidth>=255 set to 254 or something. About the issue raised by Nick Points vs Character. Any ideas on how to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my comments, something like below should work. I worked out the ratio of points to columnwidth directly in the code, as this could change based on the font size of the normal style.

```
Sub TestWH()

'Get widths
WinWidth = ActiveWindow.UsableWidth

'work out the ratio between pixels and columnwidth
ratio = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).ColumnWidth / ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Width

RangeWidth = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:AE1").Width

'work out the size in columnwidth values
adjcolwidth = ((WinWidth - RangeWidth) / 2) * ratio

'If less than 4 then set to 4
If adjcolwidth < 4 Then
    Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 4
ElseIf adjcolwidth < 255 Then
    Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = adjcolwidth
Else
    'what do you want to do if it's greater than 255?
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This look promising. Will give it a try and report Back as soon as i get some free time and all the christmas presents are opened. Happy christmas holiday everyone :)

Comment: It worked great. The last thing to figure out is to run this every time a user changes the active window size or use zoom. Im not actually sure its possible to make this a realtime thing.